# how to initialize tomcat server in eclipse by editing config files

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration

im trying to get tomcat server setup automatically in eclipse just by adding the server folder that we get once we setup tomcat by manual
But im not able to see the tomcat server setup by doing this process.
Anyway i can modify files so that upon copying the server folder we can get the tomcat localhost setup with the run button ready to run the server?

Added Picture
[image: Server Folder we get once we do it manually]

Server setup expected picture. This is what i what should get once i add the server folder to the workspace
[image: Server setup expected picture]

what i get Actually once i add the server folder [image: Actual Tomcat server link]

Any help with this?

Comment: What server folder are you talking about: are you adding the `Servers` project or Tomcat's installation folder (`CATALINA_HOME`) to Eclipse's workspace? Anyway that is not enough, you also need to use the _"Add new server"_ wizard.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz is there a way to do the "Add new server" wizard through file editing ? as im trying to automate manual touches for setting up server in eclipse we do for our application, i was adding the Servers project